# mysql select from 2 tables by user and group by

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have 2 tables.

Users can add books to table_1.

```
bookID  titel   addedby
1       t1      user1
2       t2      user1
3       t3      user2
```

Users can select books already in table_1 and add ebooks to table_2.
They can select every bookID in table_1, as well as books added by other users.

```
ebookID bookID  content addedby
1       1       bla1    user1
2       1       bla2    user2
3       2       bla3    user1
```

Every user should see a list ONLY of his own added books and ebooks grouped by bookID.

I need an output for user1:

```
titel: t1
ebookID: 1 / bla1

titel: t2
ebookID: 3 / bla3
```

and an output for user2:

```
titel: t3

titel: t1
ebookID: 2 / bla2
```

Right now I use 2 foreach, but the problem is, if a user added an ebook but not the book, the ebook and book both don't get displayed.

```
$cur_user_id = wp_get_current_user()->ID;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE addedby = $cur_user_id ORDER BY title ASC");
foreach($results as $r) {
    echo '<a href="/edit-book/?id=' .$r->ID. '">' .$r->Titel. '<br>';
    $bookID = $r->ID;
    $fass = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE bookID = $bookID AND addedby = $cur_user_id ORDER by ebookID ASC");
    foreach($fass as $h) {
        echo "<a href=" .$h->ebookID. ">" .$h->content. "<br><br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can retrieve data from both table by only one statement.

```
select table_1.title1,table_2.ebookid,table_2.content from table_1 
inner join table_2 on table_1.bookid=table_2.bookid
where table_1.addedby=$cur_user_id or table_2.addedby=$cur_user_id
```

Comment: I tried exactly this, but the problem was the ebooks don't get grouped by bookID. There is an output for every title. And if I add "GROUP BY table_1.title" there is only 1 output for every title with 1 ebook.

Comment: i added $x = 0; and inside the foreach if ($x == 0 OR $x != $bookID) { echo $titel } $x = $bookID;. Now it is working. Thank you!